# Как сделать парсинг сайтов в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, парсер, jsoup

Я пробовал делать, но не получалось, появлялся обычные белый экран, не выводя никакого текста. Напишите сам код (можно и ссылку на код в githab) или какие-нибудь статьи на эту тему.

Comment: `"Я пробовал делать, но не получалось"` - в таких вопросах принято приводить ваши (неудачные) попытки решения...

Comment: Приведите пример, Ваших попыток.

Comment: Я решил проблему, не создал отдельное xml для хранения информации.

Comment: Здесь подробно описано, как парсить сайты в интернете. Также надо, создавать отдельные list_item.xml
https://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/11/android.html?m=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Андроид Студио - IDE для создания приложений под Android, а не программа для парсинга сайтов.

Comment: Я знаю что можно сделать парсинг сайтов через андройд студио. Если вы не можете дать ответ на вопрос, то не надо ничего писать.

Comment: Я не только могу дать ответ на вопрос, я и дал его. А если вы что-то такое знаете, то можете обратиться туда, откуда узнали. Это сайт для нормальных программистов, а не для разных перверсий. Так-то можно и диплом в фотошопе написать, а не в ворде.

Comment: Может тогда вы предложите альтернативу сбора данных, которые постоянно обновляются. Я делаю приложение для интернет-вещей. Все данные отправляются на мой сайт, поэтому я хотел брать данные с сайта. Модет как-то через БД сделать...

Comment: Приложение для андроида и это приложение должно парсить сайт, я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли.